# Python -Is there a way to sort a list of strings which contain a date and time within

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, datetime

Say this is my list of values:

`my_list = ['Version1 2016,03,12 22:30', 'Version2 2016,03,29 23:00', 'Version3 2016,04,07 16:00', 'Version4 2016,02,24 15:00']`

Is there a way to sort the list by the earliest date and time but by keeping the the Version at the front of the string.

Answer (score 3):

You'd have to parse the datetime substring when sorting:

```
from datetime import datetime

sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x.split(maxsplit=1)[1], '%Y,%m,%d %H:%M'))

['Version4 2016,02,24 15:00',
 'Version1 2016,03,12 22:30',
 'Version2 2016,03,29 23:00',
 'Version3 2016,04,07 16:00']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sorted` with a custom key:

```
list(sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: x.split(" ", maxsplit=1)[1])
['Version4 2016,02,24 15:00',
 'Version1 2016,03,12 22:30',
 'Version2 2016,03,29 23:00',
 'Version3 2016,04,07 16:00']
```

If the date is in the format you give, you do not need to parse it as a datetime, lexicographical order is enough

Comment: Also, why two identical answers?

Comment: I edited the answer on the mobile app and it created another answer that I cannot delete...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sorted` with a custom key:

```
list(sorted(my, key=lambda x: x.split(" ", maxsplit=1)[1]))
```

Comment: sorted already returns a list. And you're not parsing the date, you're sorting that string lexicograpically, which won't at all sort the date...

Comment: I thought sorted would give an iterator, you're right it is not needed. If the date format is year, month, day, time, lexicographical order is correct

Comment: Yes it returns list, actually I think it should without casting to datetime yes. But potentially more prone to errors, such as if the month field can be `9` and `11`

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
from datetime import datetime

sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(re.sub(r"Version.", "", x).strip(), "%Y,%m,%d %H:%M"))
```

Output:

```
['Version4 2016,02,24 15:00',
 'Version1 2016,03,12 22:30',
 'Version2 2016,03,29 23:00',
 'Version3 2016,04,07 16:00']
```

Answer (score 0):

THis could work as well:

```
print sorted(l, key=lambda x: int("".join([i for i in x if i.isdigit()])))
```

Answer (score 0):

using pandas

```
import pandas as pd
data = ['Version1 2016,03,12 22:30', 'Version2 2016,03,29 23:00', 'Version3 2016,04,07 16:00', 'Version4 2016,02,24 15:00']
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = pd.concat([df, df[0].str.split(" ", n=1, expand=True)], axis=1)
df.columns = ["text","version","timestamp"]
df.timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp, format="%Y,%m,%d %H:%M")
df.sort_values("timestamp")["text"].tolist()
```

**output**

```
['Version4 2016,02,24 15:00',
 'Version1 2016,03,12 22:30',
 'Version2 2016,03,29 23:00',
 'Version3 2016,04,07 16:00']
```